# How to make LiteIDE display a user-friendly watch string for a *big.Int (or your type)?

Tags: go

I'm starting my journey in programming with Google Go. Currently I use LiteIDE as my primary IDE.

I've learned how to debug and watch variables, however when add a watch for a value of `*big.Int` (from `math/big` package), what I see is `0xc20003e740` (Value) and `math/big.Int *` (Type).

How do I make LightIDE display `value.String()` or `fmt.Sprintf("%v", value)` instead?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think what you are requesting is currently possible. You should consider filing a feature request, the creator of LiteIDE is extremely responsive: https://github.com/visualfc/liteide/issues?state=open